# What breakpoints should be if the width of the bootstrap 3 grid 1500px?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good evening! Probably a stupid question, but still. Need a bootstrap 3 grid with a width of 1500px, Gutter width is 30px, what breakpoints have to be adapted adequately ?

Comment: You can easily create a customized version on the bootstrap site: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but I'm interested in what breakpoints you need a width of 1500px @CBroe

Comment: You mean the container sizes? http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes

Comment: I have a grid width to 1500px, Gutter width is 30px, but I don't fit the standard breakpoints (≥1200px) and I have to ask, what breakpoints to use with a width of 1500px @CBroe

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you want those 1500px to be the value used for let's say the @screen-lg breakpoint - then you specify that width for that breakpoint.

Comment: Excuse me, maybe I don't understand something, say the first breakpoint of 1200px, but since I have a width of 1500px, for me it is too far, and with a width of 1450px content is not visible http://uploadme.ru/image/8Ix @CBroe

Comment: Well if you want the content to be displayed differently depending on whether the viewport is wider or narrower than 1500px - then the breakpoint is 1500px, and not 1200px ...

Comment: My God, it's so simple... sorry for the stupid question,just do not understand this point @CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is completely relative to your design.

My suggestion would be first design the whole page normally. Then check at which points the design breaks. Select those points as breakpoints.

The main thing which you should take into consideration is images. Because, along with super wide resolutions, we need to start looking at the pixel density issues.

also always start with mobile first approach.

Hope this helps!